# Can not set Kendo DropDownList selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I cant set kendo dropdownlist selected item the way i want.
so far this is what i tried , but it does not seems to work

```
<select name="YolTipleri" required
                data-value-primitive="true"
                data-role="dropdownlist"
                data-text-field="Adi"
                data-auto-bind="true"
                data-value-field="GID"
                data-source="Hede.Components.DataSources.YolTipi"></select>
```

i did try to set it like this but i am getting an error

```
$("#YolTipleri").data("kendoDropDownList").value(2);
```

and  it give me error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

How can i set this value?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index) for Kendo DropDownList?

Comment: Yes, but i can not find any sample for selected item when dynamic data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be just a typo, but I have [kendo dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OsaKoVOT) working.

In first line you don't have `id` selector, which are you using in `jQuery`.

For `MVVM` binding and dataSource you can use `data-bind` attribute.

```
<select id="YolTipleri" name="YolTipleri" required
    data-value-primitive="true"
    data-role="dropdownlist"
    data-text-field="Adi"
    data-auto-bind="true"
    data-value-field="GID"
    data-bind="source: source">
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want the solution without writing the id you can use it

```
$('[name="YolTipleri"]').data("kendoDropDownList").value(2);
```